# Android sqlite adjacency model

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I'm new to android development and working in a project that needs database interactions 
when trying to create a table using the adjacency model within sqlite but compiling fail with this error message

```
 |   id  |   parentid    |   name    |
-----------------------------------------
|   1    |   null        |   animal   |
|   2    |   null        |vegetable   |
|   3    |   1           |   doggie   |
|   4    |   2           |   carrot   |
|        |               |            |
|        |               |            |
```

This is my code:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIES="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CATEGORIES+"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+category_name+
            " TEXT,parentid INTEGER ,foreign key parentid_fk(parentid) references "+TABLE_CATEGORIES+" (id));";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        //Creation required tables


        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIES);

    }
....
....
....
....
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIES);
        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

This is the error:

```
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "parentid_fk": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Categories(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,parentid INTEGER ,foreign key parentid_fk(parentid) references Categories (id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a foreign key constraint a name, you must use the CONSTRAINT keyword:

```sql
CONSTRAINT parentid_fk FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES Categories(id)
```

Alternatively, don't give it a name:

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES Categories(id)
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed the problem :D I think that I used Mysql syntax.